# Putting a drop shadow on a menu item box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my first attempt at creating an application, so apologies if my questions are misformed or misplaced.

First a question of terminology: when you click on 'file' in a menu bar and a little box appears below with options like 'quit' and 'save,' what's this box called? Is this just called a 'context menu'?

Second: how can I put a drop shadow on this box? I've seriously been tinkering and googling for the longest time with no luck. For some reason the default in visual studio express 2013, at least as I'm using it, seems to be no shadow, which looks pretty odd imo. Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<Menu x:Name="MenuBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="27" Margin="-20,-36,140.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <MenuItem x:Name="File" Header="File" Height="27" Width="39" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Foreground="#FF323334" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="1,0,4,4" Padding="6,0">



            <MenuItem x:Name="Save" Header="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="139.2" Click="Save_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Quit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="139.2" Click="MenuItem_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
        </MenuItem>

    </Menu>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I ended up getting my answer [elsewhere](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/efc3fc2a-1994-476d-9129-67eaf2fe3aff/unable-to-add-a-dropshadow-to-a-menuitem-box?forum=wpf).

Comment: What did you use for search terms? I found this pretty easily: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/02/05/using-bitmap-effects-to-create-drop-shadows-outer-glows-etc.aspx As for your first question, its just a Menu, context menu is a menu defined based on the "context" of the click, usually these are right-click menus.

Comment: @RonBeyer Maybe I'm daft, but I don't see how I can use the code from that link to get the desired effect. Where are you suggesting that it should go in the code I submitted? I've tried inserting some of those tags in a couple places to no avail. Also, looking back through my history, here are some of the google search terms I've tried: "wpf drop menu box shadow" "wpf menu item drop shadow" "wpf menuitem box shadow" "wpf context menu item box shadow" "wpf menu no shadow" "c# wpf file menu drop shadow" "c# file menu shadow" "dropdown menu box shadow".

Comment: Still not finding a solution to this problem. Anyone?